# The input in the array list is not completely reversed and it just filters only two when using FOR loop

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, for-loop

```
tweet=['hi','hope','hippo','bow']
temp=[]
for i in tweet:
    temp.append(tweet.pop())           
print(temp)
```

Am trying to reverse the string but using FOR loop it prints out only BOW and HIPPO ,
if i use WHILE loop it is perfect.
Help me solve this?

Comment: It's never a good idea to iterate over a list while you are removing things from it.

Comment: Please note that **pop()** will remove the element from the  list starting from the right to the left. At the third iteration of your **for loop**. **hippo** and **bow** are both gone. tweet will be an empty list thus the loop will terminate. that's why you only see **bow** and **hippo**.

Answer (score 1):

Because `pop` on `tweet` affects your loop iterator.
You can easily prevent this by shallow copying(`tweet[:]`):

```py
tweet = ['hi', 'hope', 'hippo', 'bow']
temp = []
for i in tweet[:]:
    temp.append(tweet.pop())
print(temp)
```

output:

```
['bow', 'hippo', 'hope', 'hi']
```

---

By the way, you can reverse a list by builtin function `reversed`:

```py
tweet = ['hi', 'hope', 'hippo', 'bow']
temp = list(reversed(tweet))
print(temp)
```

output:

```
['bow', 'hippo', 'hope', 'hi']
```

Or, you can use slicing(answered by @Ch3steR):

```py
tweet = ['hi', 'hope', 'hippo', 'bow']
temp = tweet[::-1]
print(temp)
```

Comment: Or you can even use `tweet[::-1]`.

Comment: @Ch3steR You are right. I'll add that to my answer. Thanks.

Comment: To keep things clear: there exist *function* `reversed` which return iterator, which could then be feed to `list` function (as shown in example) and there exist *method* `reverse` of `list` which do reversion in-place, i.e. if you do `tweet = ['hi', 'hope', 'hippo', 'bow']` then `tweet.reverse()` then `print(tweet)` result will be `['bow', 'hippo', 'hope', 'hi']`

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed there exist built-in `reversed` function for that task, but I want to point one thing. In your code you do `for i in tweet`: but then do not use that `i`, so basically you are doing same action independently from current element, thus you might use `for _ in range(len(tweet))` to execute it *n* times, where *n* is number of elements (length) of `tweet` following way:

```
tweet=['hi','hope','hippo','bow']
temp=[]
for _ in range(len(tweet)):
    temp.append(tweet.pop())           
print(temp)
```

Output:

```
['bow', 'hippo', 'hope', 'hi']
```

`_` by convention denotes *variable which I do not care about*.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the built-in function `reversed`:

```
print(*reversed(tweet))
```

output:

```
bow hippo hope hi
```

the issue with your code it is because you are changing the size of your `tweet` while you are iterating over in a `for` loop

if you want to use a `for` loop:

```
tweet=['hi','hope','hippo','bow']
temp=[]
for e in tweet[::-1]:
    temp.append(e)           
print(temp)
```